# Loop the array and fill value in dynamic textbox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here splitValues contains array and .split is a class in multiline texbox which is generated dynamically
now i want fill the textbox with this array. I have done this much but not getting further?

```
function InsertItems(splitValues) {
    $(".split").each(function () {           
        if (splitValues != "") {
            $(this).val(splitValues);//
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how many textbox do you have??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
$(this).val(splitValues);//
```

to this:

```
$(this).val(splitValues.join());//
```

#### Updates:

```
$(".split").each(function (i, elem) {           
     $(this).val(splitValues[i]);//
});
```

#### [Updated Demo as suggested by *`Milind`*.](http://jsfiddle.net/2nczejao/1/)

Comment: @Milind i want each array values to fill in single textbox?

Comment: @jai when i use join it put the whole array collection in each textbox